# How can I replace all instances of a url on a page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to to replace all instances of a specific url on my HTML if a condition is met. How could I do that using only Javascript, not jQuery.

I've been trying something like this:

```
if () {

$("#container").contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) this.nodeValue = $.trim($(this).text()).replace(/http://www.homepage.com/g, "http://www.homepage.com/home")
    if (this.nodeType === 1) $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/http://www.homepage.com/g, "http://www.homepage.com/home") )
})

}
```

This doesn't work because obviously the "/" in the url are messing up the regex and I'm not sure what the correct way to write it would be, but also because it is jQuery and I don't want to add jQuery to the whole site just to run this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape this forward slash character

```
"http://www.homepage.com".replace(/http:\/\/www.homepage.com/g, "http://www.homepage.com/home")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
function replace(element, oldurl, newurl){
   element.innerHTML.split(oldurl).join(newurl);
}
```

and use it:

```
replace(document.getElementById("container"), "www.old.com", "new.com");
```